# Emulating attribute form from Esri to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Is there a way to get the same type of attribute form of ArcMap into QGIS?

In ArcMap when you select a feature you get a attribute form for that feature and when you select another feature from a different layer the attribute form will automatically update to show the newly selected feature, but in QGIS you need to open a separate attribute form for each layer.

Is there a 'global' attribute form that will automatically update with the newly selected feature in QGIS?

It is not uncommon for me to be switching between 10 or so layers at a time and having 10 attribute forms docked is a bit cumbersome to navigate.

I have included screen shots of the attribute forms.

[image: Esri Attribute form]

[image: QGIS Attribute from]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute form you are using are the form view of the attribute table (a feature not present in ArcMap). As such each form is only accessible by opening the respective attribute table and switching to form view.

QGIS has other way to display form, When reviewing existing feature you may set up the identify tool to automatically open form :

[image]

or manually open form from identify result : [image]

Note that QGIS let you organise the form to your liking and allow the use of different widget for easier data entry see [here for an how to](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/forms.html#ls-forms).

Note that in the general setting option you may choose to open or hide the form after feature creation (and to reuse last entered attribute value) this apply for all layer but you may override these setting for each layer individually in their respective attribute form configuration window.

Comment: Thank you for help. i was worried i would have to have 10+ attribute tabels open